# c# code transfers into QT C++

Tags: c#, c++, qt, com

I want to make a program using COM webbrowser which is a control in C#. In C#,I wrote these code:

```
myEles = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement myEle in myEles)
    {
        if (myEle.TagName == myTag)
        {
            if (i == myIndex)
            {
                return myEle;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

And I want to transfer it into QT. I've noticed that Qaxobject is essential. But I still got stuck when enum the element in myEles, my attempt code in QT:

```
int i = 0;
QAxObject*  myEles = ui.MyWebView->querySubObject("Document");
myEles = myEles->querySubObject("All");
QAxObject* myEle;
int myCnt = myEles->dynamicCall("Count").toInt();

for (int j = 0;j < myCnt;j++)
{
    myEle = myEles->querySubObject("[int]", j);
    if(myEle->property("TagName") ==myTag)
    {
        if (i == myIndex)
        {
            myEle->dynamicCall("InvokeMember(const QString&)", "click");
            return myEle;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

With this, I can't even get the right myCnt . I just wonder how to write it  correctly.

I've tried qt foreach,but still....

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no "count" public slot you can call. Check the documentation with `myEles->generateDocumentation();` for this.

To iterate through all your properties use the function `propertyBag()`.
You will get a QMap with all properties:

```c
QAxObject* myEles = ui.axWidget->querySubObject("Document");
myEles = myEles->querySubObject("All");
QMap<QString, QVariant> map = myEles->propertyBag();
int myCnt = map.size();
for (int j = 0;j < myCnt;j++)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but the code you give can't get pass by some grammar mistake;  The problem is with this :"QMap<QString, QVariant> map = myEles->propertyBag();"

Comment: What's the exact error message? I tried it with success. Did you #include <QMap> ?

Comment: QAxObject*  myWebBrowser_QT::myEleGet(QString myTag, int myIndex)
{
 QAxObject *myEle;
 QAxObject* myEles = ui.MyWebView->querySubObject("Document");
 myEles = myEles->querySubObject("All");
 QMap<QString, QVariant> map = myEles->propertyBag();
 int myCnt = map.size();
 for (int j = 0;j < myCnt;j++)
 {
  int xxx = 0;
 }
 return myEle;
}   the above is the whole function. When I  pressed button loading this function.  It pops up a window says:"Module:5.6.0     File:global\qglobal.cpp     Line:2994  ASSERT:"id<0"in file qaxbase.cpp"